# Selenium: For loop stopping after first iteration

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a very simple for loop for following every follower of an Instagram profile using this piece of code:

```
        follow_buttons = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "Follow button xpath")
        for button in follow_buttons:

            button.click()
            sleep(5)
```

My problem is that after following the first account from the Followers list, chrome auto closes and the program stops.
What im doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure that `find_elements` returns multiple elements and not just one instance in this case? Also, i guess after doing the button click selenium is then on another page, and other buttons that had been found on the previous page are not available on that page anymore?

Comment: When i print follow_buttons i get 
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="1518dd53e48abfaf80e7f2d3f83cf0b1", element="E1E0E445C562C45C2F58DD149CA61AB0_element_23")>] that means its finding ony 1 element but why

Comment: that depends on the web page you are looking at. There is likely only one instance of that element on the page, so perhaps the element that you are passing here to `find_elements` is not what you think it is.

Comment: it could still be populating the list of elements in the dom.  It'll return immediately.  If you sleep for a bit then get the element reference array, you may get more.  Still, chances are, once you use the .click() method, the array will become stale because of a DOM update.  (Don't use element methods that change DOM while iterating an element reference array.)